# number of integers in output? simple java program

Tags: java, factors

I'm working on a simple java code that outputs all factors of a user-inputted number. How do I count and then display the number of factors outputted?

```
System.out.println("Enter an integer to be factored:");
int d = Stdin.readInt();

System.out.println("The Factors of " + d + " are:");
for(int w = 1; w <= d; w++ ){
    if(d % w == 0){
        System.out.println(w);
    } 
}
```

In the code above, it's the number of integers outputted in 'w' For instance, if the number inputted is 8 and its factors are 1,2,4,8, how do I write a code that says '8 has 4 factors' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You simply need a variable to count factors:

```
System.out.println("Enter an integer to be factored:");
int d = Stdin.readInt();
int nFactors = 0;

System.out.println("The Factors of " + d + " are:");
for(int w = 1; w <= d; w++ ){
    if(d % w == 0){
        System.out.println(w);
        ++nFactors;
    } 
}
System.out.println(d + " has " + nFactors + " factors");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter variable. Here is the code:

```
int counter =0;

for(int w = 1; w <= d; w++ ){
        if(d % w == 0){
        counter++;   
        System.out.println(w);

        } 

System.out.println(d + " has " + counter + "factors ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmbalzadoFactorial {
    public static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Number, i;
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please Enter any number to Find Factors: ");
        Number = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("The factors are: ");
        for(i = 1; i <= Number; i++) {
            if(Number%i == 0) { 

                System.out.format(" %d  ", i);
            System.out.print ("and");
            System.out.format("%s %n ", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```